# My 1TB WD hard drive has failed. Can it be fixed?

Tags: windows-7, usb, external-hard-drive

My 1TB WD hard drive contained more than 400 movies. It has failed. I used it in connection with a WD TV HD Media Player to watch the movies on my TV screen. I unplugged the drive one day without “ejecting” it and the drive hasn’t worked since.

My computer doesn’t recognize the USB HD (except for the BIOS settings, which do show the drive). Disk Management, however, shows an unknown device, and I can’t access it on my computer or on any other computer.

I’ve received estimates for fixing it beyond what the drive and movies are worth, but I’m still holding on to it in case someone might be able to tell me what happened and how I can recover all the movies. They took me two years to compile. I can get another WD USB HD, but I don’t have the time to re-compile all the movies.

Is there any way to fix this drive?

Comment: Can you right click the device in disk management and initialize? After doing so it may ask you to format, so do NOT do that if it does.
Also you can try using Partition Wizard, its a free tool that maybe allow you to cascade the file system on the drive since you can not do so through windows. I would check this out: http://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html

Comment: Thanks very much for answering my plea.  I've tried both of your suggestions, but they don't work.  Any program I triy gives me the following message for the WD HD: "WD Hardware Error USB Device".

In Disk Management I get the following message: "Disk 2 Unknown, Not initialized."

Tried to initialize it by right clicking on the drive and got an error message saying "The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error."

Yet it shows up in the BIOS prior to booting up Windows.

Comment: hmm have you tried running the Western Digital Data Life Guard diagnostic tool that WD has available? You can download it from here (just select your hard drive type, green, blue, etc..: http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?DL
 Then just follow these instructions: http://support.wdc.com/KnowledgeBase/answer.aspx?ID=1083   Hopefully this can give you some more information regarding your issue

Comment: I did as you suggested and failing again, I have to assume that the drive is gone forever short of sending it out to a data recovery service and the cost of that is the worst possible solutions.  Here is the info I received when I ran WD's diagnostic tool.   Data Lifeguard's upper panel shows 3 drives: Drive 1 C:, Drive 2 F:.  Model Number displays "WD HARDWARE ERROR (USB), & the S/N but lists capacity as 0 MB and SMART Status "Not Available".  The Logical Panel only shows my two internal hard drives, C: and F:.  Thanks for your help though. (NOTE: Superuser shld allow for photos & more text.)

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry to hear about your massive movie collection. I'd recommend you to check the HDD's health and SMART data by running the QUICK AND EXTENDED tests using [WD's Data LifeGuard Diagnostics for Windows](http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en).

However, considering the troubleshooting you've done so far, it seems like the drive might have failed or at least, the file system got corrupted for sure. This is usually what happens when you eject a hard drive without safely removing it.

I wouldn't recommend any data recovery attempts by yourself without checking the HDD's SMART attributes first. If there are bad sectors, the data stored on those sectors would be corrupted as well. Instead, I'd suggest you to check [WD's Data Recovery Partners Worldwide](http://support.wdc.com/Warranty/dataRecovery.aspx?lang=en) and consider getting in touch with one of them.

In the future, I'd strongly recommend you to keep at least one other copy of your files stored on a different storage device. This is the best way to avoid any data-loss headaches.

Comment: That was exactly how I destroyed the USB Drive.  I removed it from my WD TV Media Player without ejecting it properly.  See my answer above for the results of using WD's diagnostic program.  I didn't run the Write 0's test because if there IS a way to get those movies back, I didn't want to take the chance.  One of these days I may decide to try removing the disks myself and putting them into another HD chassis.

Comment: I just saw them, I'd suggest you check your BIOS settings and make sure that you have the SMART data reading enabled for all your HDDs. This way you'd be notified if any HDD errors occur and it will also allow you to monitor the SMART attributes/statistics of your drives. However, I'd still advise you to consult with a professional data recovery service for your WD external. :( These results definitely seem concerning and I'd not recommend you to risk further damage on your files by doing data recovery attempts by yourself. Keep me posted, though.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Yes, the SMART functions check out okay as the WD diagnostics shows for both of my internal hard drives as well as the non-working USB drive.  For the time being I'm just going to hold on to it in hopes that the future may provide an answer for me.  This is just a hunch but I think the USB drive may have had something on its motherboard destroyed by a potential unwarrranted charge from improperly disconnecting the drive.  The disks still spin and unless the FAT is destroyed, they might still be fully recoverable.  

Thanks to everyone for the help.